# Resize div width by dragging border not corner in React JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, resize

I'm working on a feature in my React project where a user hovers over the right or left border of the div, which could contain an image or just text or any stuff, a resize button appears on the border and while dragging the mouse will resize the div width and it's contents accordingly.

I tried the CSS Property Resize but it allows me only to drag from a corner. I want to resize the div width by dragging the border

```
.container{
  background-color: black;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

.resizable{
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: 200px;
  max-width: 350px;
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

```
<div class="container" >
  <div class="resizable">
    <p>Resizable Panel</p>
     
  </div>
</div>
```

I found few answers but all of them include JQuery. I am looking for a pure Reactjs solution.
Please don't disappoint me and tell me there's no way to achieve this. I didn't find enough information on w3.org but I'm still putting some hope in this.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There is a way to achieve this.
You can search for a React component that somebody has already created (for example [react-resizable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-resizable)). You just gonna have to fiddle with the css styles for a bit to suit your needs.
Also, you can always try and write your own reusable custom component, which can be a great starting point

Comment: But how to make it without using any external library?